# Why does the first fuunction of let output true and the second one false?

Tags: javascript

Why does maxNum and textMax be true when the code is ran and testMin and minNum become false? I am pretty confused about this. Does this have to do with the let function in js?

```js
let maxNum = Number.MAX_VALUE; 
let testMax = maxNum + 10; 
console.log(maxNum, testMax, maxNum === testMax); 
 
let minNum = Number.MIN_VALUE; 
let testMin = minNum / 10; 
console.log(minNum, testMin, minNum === testMin);
```

Comment: `testMin` is `0` (because you have exceeded the floating point range), not `false`.

Comment: and why is the testMax still the same when its + 10 added to it?

Comment: Because during the floating point add the shift to align the significant bits of `10` with the bits of `maxNum` causes the value to become `0` (since there aren't enough bits in the computation to hold them).

Answer (score 1):

`Number.MAX_VALUE` is the maximum non-infinity, non-BigInt number that can be represented in the engine. If you try to add a value to `Number.MAX_VALUE` above the last digit of precision (such as 1e302), you'll get Infinity. (If you try to add a value *below* the last digit of precision, it'll just be dropped, and you'll still be left with `Number.MAX_VALUE`)

`Number.MIN_VALUE` is somewhat similar - it's the smallest positive non-zero number that can be represented. It's not possible to go any lower without reaching 0. If you divide `Number.MAX_VALUE` by 10, you'll get a number too close to 0 to be represented as anything else, so the engine gives you 0 in response.